# Would this be the correct way to refer to two authors' separate books as one book, "Author 1 and Author 2's Books"?

Tags: possessives, compound-subjects

Say I have two authors that each wrote a book (not together) and I want to refer to both of them in one sentence while lumping their books into one noun, should I put an apostrophe right after the second author?

Answer (score 1):

You should make them **both** possessive if they do not share ownership of the books.

For example:

> I read Stephen King's and J.K. Rowling's books.

If they wrote books *together* then you would only pluralise the last in the list.

It all comes down to *ownership*, or *co-ownership*. If they are co-owners, or co-authors, then they are grouped together and are made possesive as a group noun, for example:

> - I'm at my mum and dad's house. (they own the house together, so one is possessive)
> - I've been to John's and David's houses (two different houses, so both are made possessive)

As an alternative to your example, you could also write:

> I read the books of [author 1] and [author 2].

This example doesn't need possessive nouns.

Comment: Surely **to John's and David's houses** (rather than **house**) if there are two houses. **To John's and David's daughter** (singular) would imply that both men were her parents, not that there were two daughters involved.. https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/joint-possessives/

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.

Comment: @RonaldSole Only if John and David own more than one house each. If the daughter were both John and David's then she would be "John and David's daughter".

Comment: @Astralbee It's definitely *John and David's daughter* if they are co-parents. But the phrase *John's and David's houses* is ambiguous in terms of how many houses they each own. They could each own only one house, and the sentence would be exactly the same.

Comment: @Astralbee And "John's and David's house* in your answer is wrong, no matter what it's describing. They can't individually own the same house.